# ActionBarSherlock option menu and the error/warning : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/ic_go_search_api_holo_light.png

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock in my project and it is working quite well. But sometimes, I get problems about the option menu. When the user presses on one menu item, the app starts another activity, but sometimes it delays a little bit and I can press on the menu item many times, and it starts many other activities.

1. I don't know whether it is `ActionBarSherlock` problem or the Android OS have time delay when it starts another activity.
2. I see these logs in logcat when the orientation changes. I searched in google about it, but I can only see one post in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/YRk2O3Rckyw/UOIME4EQx5MJ) and there is no solution. If you are using ActionBarSherlock do you see these kind of logs ? or do you know why it happens ?

> 10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   res/drawable-mdpi/ic_go_search_api_holo_light.png in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled-2.apk]
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:463)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:366)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:147)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:97)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:90)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.support.v4.app._ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse.onCreatePanelMenu(_ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse.java:45)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:556)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:483)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:273)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat$1.run(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:988)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4137)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/dalvikvm(7718): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'res/drawable-mdpi/ic_go_search_api_holo_light.png'
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718): Cannot instantiate class: res/drawable-mdpi/ic_go_search_api_holo_light.png
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   res/drawable-mdpi/ic_go_search_api_holo_light.png in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled-2.apk]
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:463)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:366)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:147)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:97)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:90)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.support.v4.app._ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse.onCreatePanelMenu(_ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse.java:45)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:556)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:483)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:273)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat$1.run(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:988)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4137)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>       10-28 08:21:36.054: W/MenuInflater(7718):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help me and sorry because my english is not really well.

Comment: did you add the library to the project build path

Comment: of course. The app is running but in logcat I see the warning.

Comment: I actually have the same issue on android 3.1 and 3.2..